# clang-tidy and boost::intrusive_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, clang-tidy

I use `boost::intrusive_ptr` in my project and have such code:

```
void foo(boost::intrusive_ptr<MyObject> obj) {
    // do something with obj
}
```

And I have clang-tidy diagnostic:

```
Clang-Tidy: The parameter 'obj' is copied for each invocation but only used as a const reference; consider making it a const reference
```

But `boost::intrusive_ptr` copying on function invocation is intended usage of it, because it's wrapping a pointer and usually we don't want to add one more level of indirection. There are no such diagnostic for `std::shared_ptr` which have similar usage.

How to add `boost::intrusive_ptr` to the list of clang-tidy exceptions for this diagnostic rule to avoid false warnings?

Comment: Why don't follow the suggestion and declare `void foo(const boost::intrusive_ptr<MyObject>& obj)`?

Comment: If you don't take shared-ownership and the pointer isn't expected to be null, just pass `MyObject&`

Answer (score 0):

Clang-tidy has a configuration file (`.clang-tidy`) in which you can specify options for checks. According to https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/performance/unnecessary-value-param.html the offending check has an option to ignore specified types. I think it should be something like

```
CheckOptions:
    - key: performance-unnecessary-value-param.AllowedTypes
      value: ^boost::intrusive_ptr<.*>$
```

in the `.clang-tidy` file. The file path can also be given explicitly with `--config-file` or the configuration can be given as a string in the `--config` command line argument. See the documentation for details.

The value field is a semicolon-separated list of regex to match against.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If</strike>Since you don't take shared-ownership and the pointer isn't expected to be null, just pass `MyObject&` or `MyObject const&`. It's simpler, more expressive and less tightly coupled. (Now you can use the function e.g. in a unit test without needing the unrelated `intrusive_ptr` for the occasion).

If it can be null, you can pass `intrusive_ptr<MyObject> const&`.